# Pascal ABC .NET Ошибка: Unit1.pas(28) : Встречено 'label', а ожидался идентификатор

Tags: pascal

Постоянно ошибка с меткой.

```
   Unit Unit1;

interface

uses System, System.Drawing, System.Windows.Forms;

type
  guessanumber = class(Form)
    procedure textBox1_TextChanged(sender: Object; e: EventArgs);
    procedure label1_Click(sender: Object; e: EventArgs);
    procedure button1_Click(sender: Object; e: EventArgs);
  {$region FormDesigner}
  internal
    {$resource Unit1.guessanumber.resources}
    button1: Button;
    label1: &Label;
    label2: &Label;
    label3: &Label;
    textBox1: TextBox;
    {$include Unit1.guessanumber.inc}
  {$endregion FormDesigner}
  public
    constructor;
    begin
      InitializeComponent;
    end;
  end;
label
    rand;
var 
  sa: string;
  bs: string;
  a,b: integer;
  rng: Random; 
implementation
procedure guessanumber.textBox1_TextChanged(sender: Object; e: EventArgs);
begin
end;

procedure guessanumber.label1_Click(sender: Object; e: EventArgs);
begin
rand:
  rng := Random.Create; // Создаем экземпляр класса Random 
  a := Trunc(rng.NextDouble * 100);
end;

procedure guessanumber.button1_Click(sender: Object; e: EventArgs);
begin 
  bs := textBox1.Text;
  b := StrToInt(bs); 
  sa := IntToStr(a);
  label3.Text := sa;
    if b > a then 
      label1.Text := 'Много';
    if b < a then
      label1.Text := 'Мало'; 
    if b = a then 
  label1.Text := 'Угадал';
  goto rand;
   
end;
  
end.
```

Comment: ну так попробуйте убрать `label rand;`

Comment: Мне нужны метки для того чтобы переходить по ним

Comment: а, что, по-вашему, должно произойти после выполнения `goto rand;` внутри процедуры обработки события?

Comment: Ну тогда как мне это сделать?

Comment: сделать что? что должно выполняться после `goto rand`?

Comment: Если условие верно a = b то мы заново начинаем код

Comment: У вас код основан на событиях от контролов.  Ничего вы заново не начинаете. Выкиньте goto.